# Ajax + Spring Boot/Spring MVC/Jackson + data is truncated?

Tags: java, json, ajax, rest, spring-mvc

I have a Spring Boot/Spring MVC website with HTTPS.  On my pages, I use a basic AJAX call to get JSON data which is served by a @RestController, but it appears to be truncated or something that I don't understand fully.

When I call the REST endpoint by itself, I get a full screen of the output--its a list of POJOs that I use Jackson to serialize.  When I call it via ajax, I get it truncated or something.

When I send it to the console to see what I'm getting:

```
console.log("now returning this:");  //shows 'now returning this'.
console.log(response); //returns Array [ Object, 13, 15, 19 ]
```

The first thing in the response is always an object, but if there is more than 1, then I'll get a list of numbers that seem to point to the @JsonIdentityInfo generated IDs.

So the pojo looks a little like this:

```
@JsonIdentity(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property="@id")
@Entity
@Table (name = "tablename")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) //because Jackson keeps throwing in new stuff
public class Table {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "columnname")
    private Long id;

    .....lots of properties and gets/sets

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "col2", referencedColumnName = "col2", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @JsonBackReference(value = "blah")
    @JsonIgnore
    private OtherObject obj;

    ....more gets and sets.  The OtherObject class has the ManagedReference....
}
```

In my javascript:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "../mytesturl/" + ID,
   dataType: "json",
   contentType: "application/json",
   timeout: 1000000
}).done(function (response) {
   console.log("now returning this:");  //shows 'now returning this'.
   console.log(response); //returns Array [ Object, 13, 15, 19 ]
});
```

My RestController is pretty basic (just lots of rows):

```
@RestController
public class RestController {
   @RequestMapping(path = "mytesturl/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
   public String getById(@PathVariable("id") Long id) throws JsonProcessingException {
      List<Objects> list = dao.findAllById(id);
      return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(list);
   }
}
```

When I examine the results of the REST call by calling it with the browser, I get a whole huge list with all the references and back references and stuff.  Great.  It appears to be all there.

When I go through the ajax call, I get Array[Object, 1, 2, 3].

I hunted around and thought maybe it was a weird parsing thing or maybe truncation.  I do have

```
server.compression.enabled = true
```

So I guess it's compressing (using the internal Tomcat).

Does anyone have any ideas?  I do not recall having this problem when I was using Gson and I can plainly see that Jackson is putting in a bunch of "helpful" extra fields, so I can see that there might be some compression setting needed or some kind of buffer limit increased.

Comment: Are you implementing Serializable to the subclasses?

Comment: Yes.  They are serializable.

Answer (score 0):

In your ajax function done try to Use

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
```

and in your rest controller return a list of objects (it's work with me I used to  return a List of objects like `List<Car>`):

```
@RestController
public class RestController {
   @RequestMapping(path = "mytesturl/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
   public List<Objects> getById(@PathVariable("id") Long id) throws JsonProcessingException {
      List<Objects> list = dao.findAllById(id);
      return list ;
   }
}
```

Comment: OK.  I can see that there is a big JSON object in the [0] and then the numbers.  I am expecting an array of json objects, which would appear in the Firebug console as Array [Object, Object, Object.....] rather than Array[Object, 1, 2, 3....].

Comment: So why are you return a String instead of a List of objects in your rest controller method I update my response